# $(a+b+c+d)^{10}$ expansion such that the powers are different from 2

Tags: combinatorics

We can rewrite the question as $x+y+z+w=10$ and $x,y,z,w \not=2$, how many integer values fulfill the condition ?

i know how to solve the question when the constrain is $>$ and not $\not=$.

Comment: I think is confusing to use the same labelings for variables and exponents, maybe you can change it to $(x+y+z+w)^{10}$?

Comment: Usually this problems with the restriction $\neq$ are better solved with inclusion-exclusion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding 
$$A=\{(x,y,z,w)\geq 0\hbox{ such that }x+y+z+w=10, x,y,z,w\neq 2\}$$
 Let's find the complement
$$A^c=\{(x,y,z,w)\geq 0 \hbox{ such that }x+y+z+w=10, x=2 \hbox{ or }y=2 \hbox{ or }z=2 \hbox{ or }w=2\}$$
This complement can be expressed as a union of the sets 
$$A^c=\bigcup_i\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\geq 0\hbox{ such that }x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10, x_i=2\}$$
To get cardinality of the union of sets you can use inclusion-exclusion method. At the end you will get
$$|A^c|={4\choose 1} |B_3(8)|-{4\choose 2}|B_2(6)|+{4\choose 3}|B_1(4)|$$
Where 
$$B_k(n)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_k)\geq 0:x_1+\dots+x_k=n\}$$
We know that $|B_k(n)|={n+k-1\choose k-1}$.